# Knockout Validation - Validation not binding to correct instance of object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using [knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) and am having a problem with the error messages not showing correctly after changing what observable an input field is bound to.

### I have the following html

```
<div id="editSection" data-bind="if: selectedItem">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input data-bind="value:selectedItem().FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input data-bind="value:selectedItem().LastName" />
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<table data-bind='if: gridItems().length > 0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: gridItems'>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind='text: FirstName' ></td>
            <td data-bind='text: LastName' ></td>
            <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.editItem'>Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### And JavaScript

```
var lineViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.FirstName = ko.observable(first).extend({required:true});
    this.LastName = ko.observable(last).extend({required: true});

    this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
}

var mainViewModel = function() {
    this.gridItems = ko.observableArray();
    this.gridItems([new lineViewModel('first1'), new lineViewModel(null,'last2')]);

    this.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    this.editItem = function(item){
        if (this.selectedItem()) {
            if (this.selectedItem().errors().length) {
                alert('setting error messages')
                this.selectedItem().errors.showAllMessages(true);
                }
            else{
                this.selectedItem(item)
            }
            }
        else
            this.selectedItem(item)
    }.bind(this)
}

ko.applyBindings(new mainViewModel());
```

### Reproduce

Use this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnwv0c1s/)

1. Click Edit on the first line
2. Click Edit on the second line - You will be alerted of validation
   message being shown and then it will show
3. Fill out required field
4. Click Edit on the second line again - You will see "First Name" go
   blank and "Last Name" change to "last2"
5. Click Edit on the first line - You will be alerted of validation
   message being shown, BUT it's not show (BUG)

Should I take another approach to this or should I do something different with the way that I am using ko.validation.group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is fine... your edit section has problems.

Use the `with` binding.  Never use `someObservable().someObservableProperty` in a binding, it will not work like you might expect it.  You should change the binding context.

```
<div id="editSection" data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input data-bind="value: FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input data-bind="value: LastName" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"it will not work like you might expect it"_ can you expand on that?

Comment: Thank you, that works. I was overlooking how I was binding that section.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: If `someObservable` changes, the binding may or may not see that change, depending on the property you access and other factors. There are no guarantees. I would just avoid that pattern always and use something more stable.

Comment: Like whether or not the parent property is observable? Your current wording doesn't really explain why it just says "Never do x". Would you mind adding the explanation so it sounds less like voodoo?

Comment: @CarrieKendall: Honestly, this is the sort of thing that really doesn't need much explaining. There's a pattern for how things should be done and there are things that are fairly acceptable. But then there's things that are inadvisable. We don't need to explain every insignificant detail.

Comment: Oh, well maybe I am the only one who would prefer more explanation :) I tend to not blindly follow patterns without understanding the why underneath. You're free to answer how you like, I just thought this _was_ significant since it seems heavily related to OP's problem

Comment: @CarrieKendall no I agree, a good explanation is never "follow what I say blindly"